# How to make Laravel 'confirmed' validator to add errors to the confirmation field?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

By default, Laravel 'confirmed' validator adds the error message to the original field and not to the field which usually contains the confirmed value.

```
'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
```

**Is there any simple way to extend the validator or use some trick to force it to always show the error on the confirmation field instead of the original field?**

If I fail to enter my password twice, the error seems more appropriate to belong the confirmation field and not to the original password field. Or maybe that's just our UX analyst getting nitpicky...

Comment: Why does this matter what field it belongs to? You can't auto-populate a password field (or at least shouldn't) so just saying the passwords don't match should be fine?

Comment: Our UI has validation messages showing as tooltips on specific fields, thus it is important to show the message where it makes more sense.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One way to go about it is to use `same` rule instead of `confirmed`

```php
// ...

$input = Input::all();

$rules = [
    'password' => 'required|min:8',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:8|same:password',
];

$messages = [
    'password_confirmation.same' => 'Password Confirmation should match the Password',
];
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes Laravel is confusing because it's possible to achieve similar results in different ways. `same` turned out to be more customizable than `confirmed`

Answer (score 9):

You should design your form as below;

```
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
```

Quote from Laravel: **confirmed**
"The field under validation must have a matching field of foo_confirmation. For example, if the field under validation is password, a matching password_confirmation field must be present in the input"

Now, you can design your validation as follow;

```
$request->validate([
        "password" => 'required|confirmed' 
    ]);
```

Comment: But where will the error message be displayed? With your solution, it seems, that the error message will be displayed under the password input field and not under the confirmation field, and that is the problem because it causes confusion for user.

Comment: If the password and password confirmation does not match, where the error message displayed is not important. Because you do not know which field is desired password. Validation focuses on to be same password for both fields.

Comment: Well, our Quality Assurance person did not agree with that. He insisted that if the error message says "Password confirmation does not match password" then it should be displayed under the confirmation field and not under password field. I guess, that's subjective but I kinda see his point - it's the confirmation that is wrong and not the password.

Answer (score 4):

```
$rules=[
            'username'=>'required|max:20',
            'password1'=>'required|min:8',
            'password2'=>'required|min:8|same:password1',
        ];
        $error_messages=[
            'password2.same'=>'password are not the same password must match same value',
            'password1.min'=>'password length must be greater than 8 characters',
            'password2.min'=>'confirm-password length must be greater than 8 characters',


        ];
        $validator=  validator($request->all(), $rules, $error_messages);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('control_pannel/change_password')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that quickly comes to mind is to just display the `password` errors on the `password_confirmation` field.

If that won't work for you, just label the `password_confirmation` field as password and the `password` field as password confirmation so that if there are errors, it will show up near the `password_confirmation` label rather than the `password` label.

Otherwise, it's not difficult to add a your own custom validation method.