# Laravel password validation fail on "min length" if empty

Tags: php, laravel, validation

My validator rule looks like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name'     => 'required|min:5|max:255',
        'email'    => [
            'required',
            'max:255',
            'email',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id),
        ],
        'password' => 'min:6|confirmed',
    ], [
        'confirmed' => 'Hasło musi się zgadzać',
        'unique'    => 'Wpisz inny adres email, ten adres jest zajęty',
        'required'  => 'To pole jest wymagane.',
        'min'       => 'To pole musi mieć minimum :min znaków.',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/panel/users/'.$id.'/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
```

When i edit user without change password, validator fails with 'min' rule. As you can see my validator doesnt require password, so why it validating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's look like what you want.

```
$validator->sometimes('password', 'min:6|confirmed', function ($input) {
    return (strlen($input->password) > 0);
});
```

Comment: it's work perfectly for me as per my scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

use nullable rule

```
'nullable|min:6|confirmed'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are coming across expected behaviour.

**min:value**

*The field under validation must have a minimum value. Strings, numerics, and files are evaluated in the same fashion as the size rule.*

as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-min).

You can use the `sometimes` rule

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed',
]
```

Comment: Ok but what if i want check this only when user type new password?

Comment: You can use `sometimes` as a rule before the value.

Comment: i added sometimes as rule and still its validating for min length. ``'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed',``

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sometimes` for this case:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:6',
]);
```

You can read more about `sometimes` [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#conditionally-adding-rules):

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a
>   field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly
>   accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:

`confirmed` seems as if it can also cause a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30173098/1561929). So try doing it manually:

```
'password' => 'required|min:6',
'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6|same:password',
```

Comment: i added sometimes as rule and still its validating for min length. ``'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed'``

Comment: still doesn't work :( i mean it still warn me about min length of password even if i didn't type anything.

Comment: This only works if you are using Javascript or some other means to only submit the value of the input when there is text present. Sending an empty string to Laravel validator means it is present in the input array, so the sometimes rule passes it along to the next rule, which is the min value. That's why you still get a failure. The only way to do this without changing your frontend code is to write a manual rule that checks for strlen > 0 and then compares it to the min requirement only if it's present and has length.